# Should Ansible compile and test code before deployment, or should it only deploy compiled, tested code

Tags: continuous-integration, ansible

I'm used to having a single entity checkout, build, test, and deploy code, on every commit change (whether it be for a staging server or a production server). Now that we have started looking into Ansible, I'm beginning to think that there are isolated roles with these tools.

Basically I'm asking is it Ansible's responsibility to handle compiling and testing the code before deployment, or should it grab artifacts from a CI server such as Bamboo and trust that artifact is ready for deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the idea of using ansible to do the compiling, I rather just do that inside of CI as they have facilities done just for that. As for testing it depends on type of tests - if those are unit tests then they should be ran right after build (preferably inside of CI again) and either fail or pass a build.

But if those tests are of integration/functional nature (where they verify whether service actually works in the environment as we expect) then they for sure should be a part of post_tasks of the playbook, and if they don't pass you should mark the deployment as failed and act accordingly. This of course gives an idea of having a safe way to do that, before the service is exposed to production traffic, so if the tests do not pass, you can safely unroll the thing.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, Ansible's responsibility is not to handle compiling and testing the code before deployment.

Yes it should grab artifacts from a CI server such as Bamboo and trust that artifact is ready for deployment.

> Ansible is a radically simple IT automation engine that automates cloud provisioning, configuration management, ***application deployment***, intra-service orchestration, and many other IT needs.

https://www.ansible.com/how-ansible-works